# Motherboard speaker

Tags: motherboard, speakers

In this picture there are two buzzers.

[motherboard speakers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia6aA.jpg)

The first internal speaker is properly connected?
The second internal speaker is properly connected?

Comment: The wiring is correct as mentioned in the single answer, but it's worth mentioning that it generally doesn't matter for piezoelectric buzzers.  The polarity _does_ matter if they are traditional electromagnetic speakers, but almost nobody uses those anymore for this type of thing.  In either case, you won't damage the motherboard by wiring it wrong, you just won't have properly working sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (left) is for a speaker with a built-in amplifier. The second (right) is for the normal PC speaker without amplifier. The one on the right is correctly wired, the one on the left is also correctly wired. Both should work.

Comment: Tested ok. There are no problems.